# Keeping browser from timing out in mvc3 app during long processing time

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC3 vb.net. In my app I have a point where 500+ emails with attachments are sent out using a for each loop to accomplish this.. Nothing is returned to the browser the entire time this is running so eventually the browser think it has timed out... I tried just having it redirect to another actionresult function after every email and that function just passes it back to the email function. This is not working and I feel the reason is that nothing is actually being sent to the browser window its self.. Is there a way to fix this issue??

```
   If _keepAlive = 1 Then
                RedirectToAction("keepAlive", "Email")
   End If

    Function keepAlive() As ActionResult
        Return RedirectToAction("SendClassSchedules", "Email")
    End Function
```

Comment: I think you need to use a helper class, I'm new to MVC3 so i can't give a definite answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an async action and set the timeout to a large value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynctimeoutattribute.aspx

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-mvc-3-long-polling-chat-site/

Answer (score 0):

In the past, we have successfully started a background thread to do the processing, then set the page to refresh itself once a second - with each refresh reporting progress.  I suppose If I was doing something like that today, I would use a page method and javascript ajax call to update the page with the progress.

Comment: Yes, using in-line long running processing on a HTTP request is ALWAYS a bad idea. It would be best to kick off a seperate thread or have a windows service/console app polling some "job pickup" location and process the sending of the emails in the background, hopefully with some resume capability, and update a file, table etc with the status. Then have your "status" page just pull the status and refresh at X interval.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(v=vs.90).aspx

I think you could change `Session.Timeout` to suit your needs better..

Comment: its not a session timeout issue, its an http timeout issue.